# how to pass dynamic value in __declspec(uuid(" ComObjectGUID ") )

Tags: c++, uuid, declspec

In my code this works absolutely fine :

```
class __declspec(uuid("842E12D3-1F2C-435D-8426-BE42150AF4DB")) guid;
```

but instead of passing a staitc value I want to pass something like this, but it gives compilation error :

```
string result("64ca9bdb-08d2-45f7-c526-8fcaa8d5abd1");
class __declspec(uuid(result)) guid; 

//"result" will have dynamic value and that's why want to pass it a variable rather than hard coding the value
```

Can someone please suggest me how to achieve this.

Thanks,
Sanam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like something that is used at compile time. So there is no way to pass a dynamic value.

Comment: but is it possible to pass a variable instead of passing the actual value. Because I need to pass the "result" which will have the actual value.

Comment: Hi,It's true that it is not possible to pass dynamic value during compile time, but it is possible to pass it during run time like this :     UUID uuid;
 string result("{822412D3-745C-535D-8676-BE41230AF4DB}");
 UuidFromString((RPC_CSTR)result.c_str( ), &uuid);
then u can pass or assign the uuid whereever u want.